# Get Thumbnail from video with Preload none attribute

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I am facing issue with HTML5 Video player. When I enable attribute `preload="none"` then it does not show thumbnail of video. I do not use any `poster` attribute for Image. I want to get thumbnail from video with setting attribute `preload="none"`.

```
<video width="100%"  controls  preload="none">
    <source src="Video/Highlight2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Thanks
Hashaam Zahid

Comment: If you do't want to attach poster image and also don't want to preload the video, then how is the browser supposed to know what to display?

Comment: main problem is that i do not want to buffering / stream automatic  when i do not click on play button .therefore i set preload attr .if you have any script which doesn't make video auto  steaming then share me .